# Fix unclaimed hardware on Ubuntu 16.04 Dell XPS 15

Tags: 16.04, drivers, dell

Results from `lshw` show two unclaimed devices. A memory controller and a SMBus. Information on those is scarce, I can't figure out what they are. Some older posts mentioning them have to do with faulty audio, but I don't have any issue whatsoever (yet - I've installed Ubuntu only 2 days ago).

```
id:    memory
description:    Memory controller
product:    Sunrise Point-H PMC
vendor:     Intel Corporation
physical id:    
1f.2
bus info:   
pci@0000:00:1f.2
version:    31
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz (30.3ns)
configuration:  
latency =   0
resources:  
memory  :   dd12c000-dd12ffff

id: serial
description:    SMBus
product:    Sunrise Point-H SMBus
vendor:     Intel Corporation
physical id:    
1f.4
bus info:   
pci@0000:00:1f.4
version:    31
width:  64 bits
clock:  33MHz
configuration:  
latency =   0
resources:  
memory  :   dd132000-dd1320ff
ioport  :   f040(size=32)
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64 bits
Processor:  i7-6700HQ
Laptop model: Dell XPS-15 (9550)
Additional information: In the *Additional Drivers* tab from *Software & Updates*, I have:

[image: Device unknown]

**My question is:** Should I care? And if so, how can I resolve these unclaimed devices issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How to interpret lshw's output**
>
> lshw displays nodes with attributes in a tree-like structure (that can
>   be in indented plain text form, HTML, XML or graphically displayed in
>   the GUI). Each node has its individual status: it be CLAIMED
>   (potentially usable) or UNCLAIMED (no driver has been detected for
>   this node), ENABLED (this device is supported and can be used) or
>   DISABLED (this device is supported but has been disabled):
>
> - a node is marked as CLAIMED if a driver (usually a kernel module or a driver within the monolithic kernel) has been loaded for it
> - a node is marked as UNCLAIMED if no specific support for it has been loaded (or lshw has been unable to identify the driver)
> - a node is marked as ENABLED if a driver has been loaded for it and is fully functional
> - a node is marked as DISABLED if the node has been disabled by a configuration, some hardware failure, etc.

- PMC is a Memory controller. The one in the image is probably related but there is no module you have to use.
- The SMBus has though. Details from a skylark sunrise system:

  ```
  Device: 00:1f.4
  Class:  SMBus
  Vendor: Intel Corporation
  Device: Sunrise Point-H SMBus
  SVendor:        CLEVO/KAPOK Computer
  SDevice:        Sunrise Point-H SMBus
  Rev:    31
  Driver: i801_smbus
  ```

  See if you have i801_smbus and if you can load the module into the kernel if that fixes this one.
- See if i801_smbus is blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
- If so try to load it and see if that fixes the unclaimed (don't uncomment the blacklisting before you are sure it works).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... I tried `find /lib/modules -regex .*i801.*` and all that is found is `kernel/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-i801.ko`.

Comment: - see if it is blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf - try to load it and see if that fixes the unclaimed (don't uncomment the blacklisting before you are sure it works).

Comment: Ha! There it is indeed. A comment says that it "causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)". I commented it out & rebooted; the device is no longer "unclaimend". Thanks again.

Comment: @DominicComtois gratz :-)